# Is there a Stack Exchange community for dance?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am learning certain Latin dance styles and I wanted to ask certain questions about them. What, if any, is the Stack Exchange community for dance-related topics?

My questions/queries are around musicality and dance tips around that.

Comment: I don't think we have one.

Comment: _Maybe_ on [Music: Practice & Theory](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), using the [dance](https://music.stackexchange.com/tags/dance/info) tag.

Comment: Only if the question is about the music of the dance. I assumed that was not the case (but maybe I'm wrong...)

Comment: If there is enough demand for it, you could propose a site on Area 51 for dance.

Comment: I came here looking for a dance community! So I would join. I have very specific questions about dance shoes.